# pip3でインストールしたneovimが起動できません

Tags: python, pip, neovim

neovimのpython3を有効にしたいです。ヘルプにしたがって

```
$ pip3 install neovim
$ nvim
-bash: nvim: command not found
```

というふうにしてneovimをインストールしてみました。しかし、インストールには成功しているはずですが、nvimコマンドが動きません。PATHが通ってないのかなとは思っているのですが、どのようにPATHを通したらいいのかわかりません。

環境はMac OS X 10.9、Python 3.5.1、pip 8.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5) という具合です。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pythonパッケージの "neovim" はPythonでVimにクライアントとして接続するためのライブラリのようですね。(https://github.com/neovim/python-client)
これをインストールしてもNeovim本体のインストール状態については面倒見てくれないはずです。
Neovimのインストールは出来ていますか？
まだならば、まずこのパッケージとは関係無くNeovimのインストールを完了させるのが先かと思います。

Answer (score 2):

pipのパッケージの説明は
`neovim        - Python client to neovim`
とあるように, pipでインストールされるのはPythonでnvimとやりとりするAPIのライブラリです．単体で動くエディターとしてのnvimは別途Homebrewなどでインストールするのでは?